# Python DataFrames Lookup with random value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas dataframe consisted of a person's travel schedule, with the Origin and Destination is stated in Postcode.

`df = pd.read_csv('schedule.csv')`

`print(df)`

```
index   Origin   Destination
0       2511     2515
1       2515     2515
2       2511     2512
3       2513     2512
```

I also have another dataframe containing lists of the building within certain postcodes

`df2 = pd.read_csv('Buildings.csv')`

`print(df2)`

```
Postcode    Name            Address
2511        Office A        A street 48
2511        Office B        B street 27
2512        Mall X          X avenue 5
2512        Mall Y          Y avenue 3
2513        School C        C street 12
2515        School D        D street 1
2515        Shop E          E street 13
```

Is there a way so that I could assign a random building with the same postcode into the `df` dataframe? for instance, the ideal output would be:

```
index   Origin   Destination    O_building      D_building
0       2511     2515           Office A        Shop E 
1       2515     2515           School D        Shop E
2       2511     2512           Office B        Mall Y
3       2513     2512           School C        Mall X
```

I have tried to use `pd.merge` since it is quite similar to using VLOOKUP function in Ms. Excel. However, `pd.merge` only accepts a unique value. I've also tried to divide the `df2` into several subsets of data depends on their postcode.

I'm still a rookie in python so it is a bit confusing for me. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

# replicate your df
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Origin": [2511, 2515, 2511, 2513], "Destination": [2515, 2515, 2512, 2512]}
)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "postcode": [2511, 2511, 2513, 2513, 2515, 2512, 2512],
        "name": ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"],
    }
)
# setting 2 empty column
df["O_building"] = np.NaN
df["D_building"] = np.NaN
# define a udf for random pick
def random_choice(row):
    row["O_building"] = np.random.choice(df2["name"][df2["postcode"] == row["Origin"]])
    row["D_building"] = np.random.choice(
        df2["name"][df2["postcode"] == row["Destination"]]
    )
    return row


# use apply to apply random pick by rows.
df.apply(random_choice, axis=1)
```

`apply` is quite a useful technique in pandas. More info on `apply` can be found in the official documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html